# average of few maximum values in r

Tags: r, max

I find monthly maximum value from daily data of many companies by this r code

```
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
Output <- aggregate(DF[,-1],
                  by=list(Month=format(DF$date,"%y-%m")),
                  FUN=max)
```

However, I could not figure out how I can change this code to find out the average of two maximum values in a month or the average of three maximum values in a month. As a new learner of r, it would be very helpful for me if you can help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `sort` the values in descending (or ascending), then take the `head` of 'n' number of values and get the `mean` by using an anonymous function call in `FUN`

```
aggregate(DF[,-1], by=list(Year_Month=format(DF$date,"%y-%m")),
       FUN = function(x) mean(head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE), 2)))
```

---

Or this can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
   group_by(Year_Month = format(date, "%y-%m")) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(-date), funs(mean(head(sort(., decreasing = TRUE), 2))))
```

Comment: Don't you want `mean` rather than `max` in `FUN`?

Comment: I want to calculate the average of two maximum value@AndrewGustar